# Core Data Error "Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class" called for another Entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

I have a tableview in which I click on index=0 it loads the list of "EntityA" and when clicked on index=1 it loads list of "EntityB".

I am trying to fetch "EntityB" using NSFetchedResultsController, but it shows "Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class" for **EntityA**.

Don't know for what reason I am getting this error. There is no relationship between **EntityA** and **EntityB**. Also, I am not creating any NSManagedObject for **EntityA**.

I tried to reset the simulator but, the error still shows up in the log.

Following is the code for fetching **EntityB**

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityB" inManagedObjectContext:del.managedContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdDate" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

self.fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:del.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

self.fetchController.delegate=self;
NSError *err;
[self.fetchController performFetch:&err];
NSLog(@"Fetch Data= %@",err);
```

Also, the NSLog for FetchData is null.

"Adding a breakpoint" for all exception does not help, as this is an error.How can I debug this issue.

Comment: `fetchController=self` ???

Comment: Show the full exception message and the stack trace. Where do you create instances of `EntityA`?

Comment: @MartinR Updated the question, any help on debugging this issue.

Comment: @andyPaul: `self.fetchController=self` still makes no sense to me. Perhaps you meant `self.fetchController.delegate=self` ?

Comment: You can use this code http://pastie.org/9185177 Note:I know this is not a fix for your code but i am using this code for this purpose that's why i shared this